# VirtualTreeview enabling and disabling columns

Tags: delphi, virtualtreeview

I have a VirtualTreeView which has some columns initially hidden (`coVisible` is not present).

After enabling them (adding `coVisible` to the column Options) a strange thing happens - column appears but overlaps with previous column. I can fix the problem by changing width to 1 pixel smaller, then back to original width of the column which forces some repaint which then displays column correctly.

Is there something I need to do additionally except adding `coVisible` to make the columns repaint properly?

Comment: Have you tried Header.Columns.BeginUpdate/EndUpdate?

Comment: @kobik I haven't and it did the trick! Thank you! Please make it into a short answer so I can mark it as correct.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use:

```
VTV.Header.Columns.BeginUpdate;
try
  // Enable or Disable columns...
finally
  VTV.Header.Columns.EndUpdate;
end;
```

This should keep the `Header.Columns` in sync.

Comment: This sounds like a bug

Comment: Although this works I found that after using `BeginUpdate`/`EndUpdate` setting `VTV.Header.Columns[n].Position` won't work anymore (the value is unchanged after setting new `Position` property. As I do require to set Position, instead, I reverted to my "trick" of setting width to zero and then back to desired width.